# cordova page load is triggering unopened Modal ng-repeat scripts to run

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, controller, modal-dialog

I have a controller for template PageA.  PageA has a modal on it that ONLY opens when the user clicks a button. In the Modal is an ng-repeat; using `ng-init`, when the ng-repeat is finished (`$last`) then the `genQRCode()` function is be called.  Its done this way so that the DIVs are first created, added to the dom, before the qrcode `<canvas>` is attached to the DIV.

The problem though is that as soon as PageA loads, there is a call to `genQRCode()` even though the user has not clicked on the button to open the Modal.

BUTTON:

```
<button ng-click="openTicketModal();" class="button button-block button-large-custom" style="">View Tickets</button>
```

MODAL

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in club.tickets" id="ticketID_{{ticket.ticketID}}" ng-init="$last && genQRCode()">

  ... qrCode will be attached here in a <canvas> ...

</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
  $scope.genQRCode = function() {
    for (var x=0;x<$scope.club.tickets.length;x++) {
      var ticket = $scope.club.tickets[x] ;

      angular.element(document.querySelector('#ticketID_'+ticket.ticketID)).empty() ;
      
      jQuery('#ticketID_'+ticket.ticketID).qrcode({width:150,height:150,text:ticket.qrString}) ;
    }
  } ;

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('ticketModal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    backdrop: 'static',
    backdropClickToClose:false,
    focusFirstInput: false 
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.tixModal = modal;
  });
  
  $scope.openTicketModal = function(id) {
    $scope.tixModal.show() ;
  } ;
  $scope.closeTicketModal = function(id) {
     $scope.tixModal.hide() ;    
  }  ;
```

My expectation is that the user clicks the button, the Modal opens, the ng-repeat fires....then on the `$last` one trigger the `genQRCode()` function.

What is happening to cause the `genQRCode()` to be triggered even before the modal opens?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this issue, I resolved with a bit of a hacky fix.

On the ng-repeat, I removed the `ng-init="$last && genQRCode()"` and in the Modal open function I added an `$interval` to check to see if the last element of the ng-repeat has been rendered to the DOM, and when it has, then trigger the genQRCode() function.  It works.  Its the ONLY thing I could figure out to work - adding the ng-init or a `directive` to the ng-repeat did not help because both of them triggered a call to `genQRCode()` when the controller/page loaded - and the modal DOM elements weren't created yet.:

```
  $scope.openTicketModal = function() {
    $scope.ticketInit = $interval(function() {
      $scope.refreshTickets = 1 ;
      var tid = $scope.club.tickets.length-1 ;
      if (angular.element('#ticketID_'+tid)) {
        $interval.cancel($scope.ticketInit) ;
        $scope.genQRCode() ;
      }
    },100) ;
    $scope.tixModal.show() ;
  }
```

Comment: My solution works...until you close the modal, route to a different page - then route back to the modal page and open the modal again.  The ng-repeat DIVs are all there, but the jQuery qrCode generator isn't able to attach the image again.   Back to square one.